# Superset sql query editor using parameter in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, jinja2, apache-superset

I am trying to use a parameter in where clause of a query. This query is going to run on an instance of a mysql database. This is my sample query that finds expired orders:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status = "expired"
```

I want the status part to be dynamically filled during visualization. When I replace it with a parameter like this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status = {{ status }}
```

and define the parameter as:

```
{"status": "expired"}
```

I get this error:

> Unknown column 'expired' in 'where clause'

It seems it is because of double quotation around expired.
I can use parameters successfully outside of where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just missing one quote here.

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status = '{{ status }}'
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Is there any way I set the parameter when viewing chart not in sql lab?